# Huisken's monotonicity formula (mean curvature flow)

Tags: differential-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Let $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and define the backward heat kernel relative to $(x_0, T )$ as

$\rho_{x_0}(x,t)=\frac{e^{-\frac{|x-x_0|^2}{4(T-t)}}}{\sqrt{4\pi(T-t)}}$.

The article that I'm reading says that

[image]

where

$\gamma$ is a curve,

$div^\top \ $ means tangential divergence,

$s$ is the arcleght parameter,

$\tau$ is the unit tangent vector to $\gamma$,

$\nu$ is the unit normal vector to $\gamma$,

$\underline{v}$ in the velovity of the point $\gamma(x,t)$,

$\lambda$ is the tangential velocity of the point $\gamma(x,t)$,

$k$ is curvature at the point $\gamma(x,t)$.

Moreover, we set $\underline{\lambda} = \lambda\tau$ and $\underline{k} = k\nu$, then, it clearly follows that $\underline{v} = \underline{\lambda} + \underline{k}$.

Now, I can't understand how to transition from the first line of the formula to the second.